# Magento 1.9 product filter by rating at category page

Tags: magento

I am using Magento 1.9 version and there i wants to show option of filter products by rating at category(product list) page. Please anyone can send script.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your rating is stored as a product attribute - You can do this using the admin panel.

Go to Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes.
Select your attribute.
Under Properties -> Used for Sorting in Product Listing -> Select Yes

Otherwise (depending on your theme)
getAvailableOrders() is the function called to populate your "sort-by" class.

data/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Toolbar.php

contains an addOrderToAvailableOrders($order, $value) function

This will add your attribute to Available Orders.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Hello Thanks for your reply. Rating is not Attribute. I want to show rating (1 star,  2 star, 3 star ... ) at left side of product list (Category). I think for it we need script. please help

Comment: Hello, is anyone please can help me.. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Here is the extension for Adding Protuct rating filter on category page https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/ratings-filter-and-sort.html

Ratings Filter works exactly like any other filterable attribute does in an 'anchored' category, composite products such as 'Configurable' include the ratings of their 'Simple' products. It is completely safe because no core files are overridden. Stars are shown as unicode characters, there are no templates to modify nor any CSS files.

Comment: Hello Abhinav,
Thanks for reply. But i wants done this by script actually client dont want to purchase extension.  By the way i have done it from code. :)